# How to create <? extends subtype> with JCodeModel?

Tags: java, generics, sun-codemodel

I've used JClass.narrow on JCodeModel to create the necessary generics for types, but I can't figure out how to generate something like this.

```
private Class<? extends Serializable> dataType;
```

How does one generate the ? extends part?

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out.  Here is an example of obtaining a JClass reference to `Class<? extends Serializable>`.  Hope it helps someone.

```
JClass temp = codeModel.ref(Class.class).narrow(codeModel.ref(Serializable.class).wildcard());
```